# radioButton and tabsetPanel automatically change in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am using shiny to display results of two methods, A and B. First I use `radioButtons` so that end-users can choose one of the methods, and then further specify in a list of drop-down menu the item to display. Since there are two methods, I also consider using "tabs" (`tabsetPanel`). My question is that, is there a way that when I click a `radioButton` of a method, then the corresponding "tabview" is automatically switched (to the desired method's display result)?

Thank you! If there is a working example that is similar to this situation that would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the help for `?updateTabsetPanel`, or `?conditionalPanel`

If you decide to go the `updateTabsetPanel` approach, you can have the selected tab change depending on user input (taken directly from the help):

```
# in server.R
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    observe({
        # TRUE if input$controller is even, FALSE otherwise.
        x_even <- input$controller %% 2 == 0

        # Change the selected tab.
        # Note that the tabsetPanel must have been created with an 'id' argument
        if (x_even) {
            updateTabsetPanel(session, "inTabset", selected = "panel2")
        } else {
            updateTabsetPanel(session, "inTabset", selected = "panel1")
        }
    })
})
```

Note the use of a `session` object and `?observe`.

If you decide to go the `conditionalPanel` approach:

```
# in ui.R
selectInput("method", "Method", c("A", "B")),
conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.method == 'A'",
    plotOutput(...)  # or whatever input/output you want
),
conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.method == 'B'",
    plotOutput(...)  # or whatever input/output you want
)
```

I don't believe `conditionalPanel` works to make conditional tabs though. (I could be wrong about this)